# Add buttons on an imageView

Tags: android, button, android-widget, imageview

I'm trying to display an imageView with some buttons on it.
My problem is that I don't find any way to add my buttons at a specifics x and y on the image, can you tell me a function to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: not logical question,tell me more what you want?

Comment: If there's an image of size 100x200, he wants to know how to place a button at 34x96. Not sure how that was hard to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

You could put the ImageView and a [AbsoluteLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html) inside a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html). Then add your buttons to the AbsoluteLayout.

Comment: ok but I don't see what function I need to call to set the coordinates :/ Do I need to set it when I create a button or when I put it on a layout?

Comment: @Imotep: http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/absolutelayout-in-android-xml.html

Comment: do you have the programmatic way? cause my buttons are in database so i can't set them in a xml file

Answer (score 2):

An ImageView is not capable of having children objects within it.  The ImageView and Buttons would have to be two child objects within a Layout.  If you want the button to appear on top of the ImageView, place the code for the Button after the ImageView code in the layout.